# `tapply()` to return data frame

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataset with a datetime (POSIXct), a "node" (factor) and and a "c" (numeric) columns, for example:

```
                 date node           c
1 2011-08-14 10:30:00    2 0.051236000
2 2011-08-14 10:30:00    2 0.081230000
3 2011-08-14 10:31:00    1 0.000000000
4 2011-08-14 10:31:00    4 0.001356337
5 2011-08-14 10:31:00    3 0.001356337
6 2011-08-14 10:32:00    2 0.000000000
```

I need to take the mean of column "c" for all pairs of "date" and "node", so I did this:

```
tapply(data$c, list(data$node, data$date), mean)
```

The result I obtain is what I want, but in a strange structure:

```
num [1:5, 1:8923] 0 0 0.00092 0.00146 NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:8923] "2011-08-14 10:30:00" "2011-08-14 10:31:00" "2011-08-14 10:32:00" "2011-08-14 10:33:00" ...
```

Where an example output would be:

```
  2011-08-17 23:56:00 2011-08-17 23:57:00 2011-08-17 23:58:00
1        4.759077e-05        4.759077e-05        4.759077e-05
2        0.000000e+00        3.875248e-05        1.595690e-04
3        1.134391e-03        1.134391e-03        1.109730e-03
4        4.882813e-04        6.914658e-04        4.955846e-04
5        0.000000e+00        0.000000e+00        0.000000e+00
```

What I was going for was something like the original structure, with a datetime, the node factor and the "c" value. I cannot figure out how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try...

```
aggregate( c ~ node + date, data = data, FUN = mean )
```

Comment: All the methods suggested above worked for me, but this turned out to be the quickest (on a dataset of over 2M rows) and produced the exact output that I wanted. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of tapply you want to use `ave`

```
data$grp.mean <- ave(data$c, list(data$node, data$date), FUN= mean)
```

Looking again at this I am wondering if you wanted to have the aggregation done on the basis of "date" in the calendar sense of 24 hours?

If you wanted to use the results you already have (assuming they are named "M") you might want to try :

```
require(reshape2)
newdf <- melt(t(M))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want output that's a data frame with three columns, you probably would benefit from looking at the `plyr` package (assuming your data are stored in `dat`):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(date,node),summarise,m = mean(c))
```

Comment: Also see Johns answer below. I'm very pro aggregate as, from my experience, on large data sets it is substantially more computationally efficient.

Comment: @nzcoops For large data sets did you see this recent article [Comparison of ave, ddply and data.table](http://www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/)?

Comment: @Matthew Dowle, that's for that. That is definitely my experience working with large data. I'll have to make the effort to learn more about data.table and incorporate it in my work. plyr is great for some things, but it baffles me why on here people continually jump to it as a first port of call when there are base functions that solve the problem... (and faster), with clearer more concise code.

Comment: It's not all that baffling when you consider that the plyr commands were designed to work coherently in a fashion for general data reshaping that the base commands just do not have; and they are better known / older than data.table. Further, the base commands have improved over time, such as the formula interfaces being better integrated, and so viewing from the current state (or even 2011) it may seem baffling but it's quite understandable when you know the history better. (Further, Hadley fans now have dplyr for speed so no need to learn data.table)